# Difference between ToArray() & ToArray<int>();

Tags: c#, .net

Excuse me if I am asking silly question, but can anybody explain the difference between following two calls (`ToArray`). In the intellisense it does not show them as overloaded methods & of course the output of both the calls are same.

```
List<int> i = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 64 };
int[] input = i.Where(j => j % 2 == 1).ToArray();
input = i.Where(j => j % 2 == 1).ToArray<int>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference here. In the first call, the compiler has inferred the type `int`, while in the second you have specified it explicitly.

There may be cases where the type is necessary because it cannot be inferred. For example, you have a custom collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>` twice, for two different types `T`. This hurts usability so it is preferable that you avoid such constructions.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference, it is the exact same ToArray() method.  The compiler can simply infer that you want the `ToArray<int>` version from the syntax of the expression.  The return value of Where() was inferred to return int.  In other words, it uses `Where<int>()`.  Which was inferred from the type of the List<>.  So it can infer that you need `ToArray<int>`.

So the type inference chain is `List<int>` => `Where<int>()` => `ToArray<int>()`.

Change the list to, say, `List<long>` and the expression still works without having to modify it.

Comment: This post or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056358/774575) should be the selected answer. The explanation of *how* the type inference can be done by the compiler is key to understanding.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same generic method. In the first case, the generic type parameter is inferred by compiler from the generic type parameter of the Enumeration you're calling `ToArray<T>()` on. But you can also specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same thing.  You are witnessing what is called "type inference".  In certain scenarios, the C# compiler can detect the type based on the parameters passed in and you do not have to explicitly specify the type parameters.  In your example, it's known that `i` is an `IEnumerable<int>`, and thus `.ToArray()` can infer the parameter `int`.

Here is a nice article that goes into this in depth: http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c/

Answer (score 3):

**No difference.**

```
int[] input = i.Where(j => j % 2 == 1).ToArray();
```

Here, only the compiler is inferring the `T` generic argument based on the type of enumerable you call `ToArray()` on.

```
input = i.Where(j => j % 2 == 1).ToArray<int>();
```

Here, return value of `Where()` is inferred by compiler to return `int`.

- `ToArray<T>()` is Generic is so that it can operate on any `IEnumerable<T>`.
- `ToArray()` actually just redirects to an implicit interpretation of `ToArray<T>()` based on the `T` of the source IEnumerable.
- If you call a generic method and don't supply any type arguments, the compiler will try to infer them for you.